# SqlAlchemy and Flask, how to query many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask

I need help creating SqlAlchemy query.

I'm doing a Flask project where I'm using SqlAlchemy. I have created 3 tables: Restaurant, Dish and restaurant_dish in my models.py file.

```
restaurant_dish = db.Table('restaurant_dish',
    db.Column('dish_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dish.id')),
    db.Column('restaurant_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('restaurant.id'))
)

class Restaurant(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)

    restaurant_dish = db.relationship('Dish', secondary=restaurant_dish,
        backref=db.backref('dishes', lazy='dynamic'))


class Dish(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
    info = db.Column(db.String(256), index = True)
```

I have added data to the restaurant_dish table and it should be working correctly. Where I need help is understanding how to correctly get a Dish using Restaurant. Raw SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT dish_id FROM restaurant_dish WHERE restaurant_id == id
```

What I have managed to get done but not working:

```
x = Restaurant.query.filter_by(Restaurant.restaurant_dish.contains(name)).all()
```

Thanks for help and I also appreciate tutorials that can point me in the right direction(the official documentation goes over my head).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The semantic of the relationship doesn't look right. I think it should be something like:

```
class Restaurant(db.Model):
    ...

    dishes = db.relationship('Dish', secondary=restaurant_dish,
        backref=db.backref('restaurants'))
```

Then, to retrieve all the dishes for a restaurant, you can do:

```
x = Dish.query.filter(Dish.restaurants.any(name=name)).all()
```

This should generate a query like:

```
SELECT dish.*
FROM dish
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM restaurant_dish
        WHERE
            dish.id = restaurant_dish.dish_id
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM restaurant
                WHERE
                    restaurant_dish.restaurant_id = restaurant.id
                    AND restaurant.name = :name
            )
    )
```

Comment: After searching for hours, `Dish.restaurant.any` was exactly what I was looking for! +1 to you!

Comment: this answer is better than any documentation.

Comment: What if I need to query all the restaurants that uses a given dish? AKA, the reverse retrieval.

Comment: Is there any way of doing `Dish.restaurants.any(thisrestaurant)` when thisrestaurant is a Restaurant intance? I could to `Dish.restaurants.any(id=thisrestaurant.id)` but it sounds a little tricky

Comment: is there any documentation about 'query.any' can't find ... ?