# How can I search the table of a Flask SQLAlchemy many to many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have the following models and table:

```
chat_members = db.Table('chat_members',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('chat_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chat.id'))
)

class chat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    chat_memb = db.relationship('user', secondary=chat_members, backref=db.backref('members', lazy='dynamic'))  
    chat_line = db.relationship('line', backref='chat_line', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Chat %r>' % (self.id)

class user(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    user_password = db.Column(db.String)
    lines = db.relationship('line', backref='line_author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.user_email)

class line(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    published_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    chat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chat.id'))
    sent_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    line_text = db.Column(db.String)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Line %r>' % (self.id)
```

I have successfully added data to all of these models but am having trouble querying the table. The ultimate goal of the query is to look up all of the chats associated with a particular user. Here is what I have done:

```
first_user = user.query.get(1)
chat.query.filter(chat_members.any(chat_memb=first_user)).all()
```

To which I got

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a collection to an
>   object or collection; use contains() to test for membership.

This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593421/sqlalchemy-and-flask-how-to-query-many-to-many-relationship) seemed very similar, but when I duplicated it for my model, I got `AttributeError: type object 'chat' has no attribute 'members'` after doing

```
chat.query.filter(chat.members.any(user_email='ACCEPTABLE_EMAIL')).all()
```

The traceback came as a surprise seeing as `members` is the backref within the `chat` model, but I feel like this query comes close.

The other relevant questions I could find did not seem to offer advice on the same search, and I could not find such queries in the official or a 3rd party many-to-many documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use joins in your query. First change your `chat.chat_memb` relationship to:

```
# Change backref from 'members' to 'chats', since the backref will be pointing
# to chat class.
chat_memb = db.relationship('user', secondary=chat_members,
                            backref=db.backref('chats', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Then use this query:

```
chat.query.join(user.chats).filter(user.id == 1).all()
```

I also recommend to follow Python style guidelines and use capitalized names for classes, e.g. `Chat` instead of `chat`. It's easy to confuse a class and an instance in your code now.

Comment: Perfect – thank you so much, both for the answer and the recommendation.