# Flask-SQLAlchemy - get the last quote from a users followed job

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My app Model is structured as so:

```
user_jobs = db.Table('user_jobs',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('job_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('market.id'))
)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    # Other user model fields....
    jobs = db.relationship('Job', secondary=user_jobs, backref='users')


class Job(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Other related fields and relationships
    quotes = db.relationship('Quote', backref='job', lazy='dynamic')


class Quote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer())
    # Other related fields
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('job.id'))
```

This model allows users to follow multiple jobs while jobs can have multiple followed users (Many to Many). A job can have multiple Quotes (One to Many).

In my flask app, I am creating a dashboard that displays the users followed jobs. For the followed jobs on the dashboard, I want to display the most recent Quote price and timestamp.

My current thinking is to create a function on the user model to return a joined table of User - Job - Quote, ordering by desc and limit(1). I however am stuck on how to do this.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
.....
def get followed_jobs(self):
return ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Given there is a list of users and I'm trying to find the latest quotes that user 1 is following, the raw SQL appears to be:

```
Select 
* 
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        job.id, job.job_name, latest_quote.timestamp, 
        latest_quote.price, user_job.user_id
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
        job_id, max(timestamp) AS timestamp, 
        price FROM quote 
        GROUP BY job_id) AS latest_quote 
    JOIN 
        job 
    ON 
        job.id = latest_quote.job_id
    JOIN
        user_job
    ON
        user_job.job_id = latest_quote.job_id
    ) as aquery
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Can this be made more efficient in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The below answer might be helpful to get the required data for many-to-many relationship. 
[SqlAlchemy and Flask, how to query many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593421/sqlalchemy-and-flask-how-to-query-many-to-many-relationship)

If you require data in serialisable format in many-to-many relationship which is your use-case, I would suggest you use nested schemas in marshmallow.

[Flask Marshmallow/SqlAlchemy: Serializing many-to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858807/flask-marshmallow-sqlalchemy-serializing-many-to-many-relationships)